# The method next() is undefined for the type String

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to call a scanner from a method- and receiving the error before compiling, I could not find an answer to this in this forum or outplace, that I could understand

```
public class BL {
    static double outcome = 0;
    private static String input;

    private static void main() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
    public static void sort() {
        **input= input.next();**     // the error is under .next()
    }
```

Thanks upfront!

Comment: A String doesn't have a `next()` method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want

```
public static void sort() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = in.next(); //or in.nextLine() for the whole line
}
```

The `Scanner` is the class that reads input from the keyboard. It is the class who has the method `next()`, that retrieves the input of the user (until it finds a space or a new line) converted in a `String`.

Comment: But cant I use the scanner inside a method?

Comment: Yes, you can, just as the example in the answer shows.

Comment: Thank you! does this mean the scanner instantiates a new instance for every time the method is called?

Comment: It depends. You can create a single static Scanner and use it everywhere or you can create an instance of it in each place you need, but remember to close the Scanner after you finish using it.